# Sharing ASP.NET Authentication between two applications

Tags: asp.net, authentication, http-status-code-401

I have two web applications ASP.NET running on the same web server IIS 7.5/.NET 4.0.
The first app makes async calls through jquery to the second app, which acts as web service backend (connected to a database server).
The two applications will be installed in intranet context, so I want to use integrated "Windows Authentication".

In both Web.config I have:

```
<authentication mode="Windows" />

<authorization>
    <deny users="?" />
</authorization>

<identity impersonate="true" />
```

If I open a browser and I access a test page it's ok on both web apps: the browser asks for a user/password pair and IIS allows the page to be downloaded.
But if I access a test page of the first web app, which makes an async request to a web service installed on the second app, a 401 error code is returned. So it seems that the authentication is lost between the two applications.

I tried also machineKey but nothing...

Any idea ?

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Alex

Comment: You said they are on the same machine, are they on the same hostname/port?

Answer (score 1):

You are probably trying to make an async request to a different domain, which [isn't allowed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest#Cross-domain_requests).

You can get around this by creating a "proxy" call to the web service.  You make the async call to your local asp.net application, which makes the call to the web service on your behalf.  This avoids the *same origin policy* restriction discussed in the link above.

Another option, since you have control of the application on both ends, would be to look at [JSONP](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).  I don't have a lot of experience with it, but I *have* seen it used for making async calls across domains.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks very much. It's the way I adopted ;-)